# multiplicative structure on the monodromy weight filtration spectral sequence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $f: X \to \Delta \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a projective morphism of a complex manifold to a small disc, smooth away from 0, and such that $Y=f^{-1}(0)$ is a strictly normal crossing divisor, and let $\tilde{\Delta^*}$ be the universal cover of $\Delta^*=\Delta \setminus \{0\}$. J. H. M. Steenbrink has [described](https://eudml.org/doc/142362) a certain double complex $A^{*,*}$ such that its total complex is a cohomological mixed Hodge complex that computes the limit mixed Hodge structure of W. Schmid on the nearby fibre cohomology $H^*(X \times_\Delta \tilde{\Delta^*}, \mathbb Q) \cong H^*(X_t, \mathbb Q)$ (the isomorphism is not canonical). It has the form
$$
A^{p,q} = \mathbb{C}u_{p+1} \otimes \Omega^{p+q+1}_X(\mathrm{log}\,Y) / W_p\\ \ \  d'(u_p \otimes \omega) = u_{p+1} \otimes dt/t \wedge \omega\qquad d''(u_p \otimes \omega) = u_p \otimes d\omega
$$
where $u_{p+1}$ is a formal variable, $t$ is a coordinate function on $\Delta$, and $W$ is the filtration by the number of poles. Steenbrink shows that there exists a natural quasi-isomorphism (given by wedging with $dt/t$ with some sign)
$$
\Omega^*_{X/\Delta}(\mathrm{log}\, Y) \otimes \mathcal{O}_Y \to \mathrm{Tot}(A^{*,*})
$$
where $\Omega^*_{X/\Delta}(\mathrm{log}\, Y)= \Omega^*_X(\mathrm{log} Y)/\Omega^1_\Delta(\mathrm{log}\,0) \wedge \Omega^{*-1}_X(\mathrm{log}\,Y)$ carries a natural multiplication.

It follows from the definition of the monodromy weight  filtration that cup product on $H^*(X_t,\mathbb{Q})$ is compatible with it.

I would like to understand the  multiplicative structure on the spectral sequence associated to the weight filtration on $\mathrm{Tot}(A^{*,*})$, so the first step is to write down a multiplication on $\mathrm{Tot}(A^{*,*})$ that would be compatible with the multiplication on $\Omega^*_{X/\Delta}(\mathrm{log}\, Y) \otimes \mathcal{O}_Y$ with respect to the aforementioned quasi-isomorphism.

**My question** is whether such multiplication exists and if yes, how one can find an explicit expression for it.

Note the strange shift in indices in the definition of the complex $A^{*,*}$: a product of a $p$-form and a $q$-form should be a $p+q-1$-form.

Perhaps there exists some complex $B^*$ with multiplicative structure, a quasi-isomorphism  $\mathrm{Tot}(A^{*,*}) \to B^*$ and a section $B^* \to \mathrm{Tot}(A^{*,*})$ (up to homotopy)?