# why is monodromy weight filtration compatible with cup product?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, monodromy

This question is about a statement I took for granted in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370953/multiplicative-structure-on-the-monodromy-weight-filtration-spectral-sequence).

If $f: X \to S$ is a moprhism from a complex manifold to a punctured disc then the monodromy operator $T$ is quasi-unipotent, so after a finite base change it may be assumed unipotent (SGA 7). The cohomology of the nearby fibre $H^*(X_\infty,\mathbb{Q})$ (where $X_\infty = X \times_S \tilde{S}$, and $\tilde S$ is a universal cover of $S$) carries a weight monodromy filtration, that is essentially obtained from applying Jacobson-Morozov theorem to the nilpotent operator $N=\log T$. In concrete terms, $W_* H^n$ is defined as follows: if $N^{m+1}=0$ but $N^m\neq 0$ then one defines the "outermost" pieces
$$
W_{2m}=H^n, W_{2m-1}=\mathrm{Im} N^m, W_0=\mathrm{Ker} N^m
$$
then inductively define $W_1, \ldots, W_{2m-2}$ by considering $N$ on the subquotient $W_{2m-1}/W_0$, where $N^m=0$, and pulling back the filtration there back to $H^n$.

Clearly, $T(a \cup b) = Ta \cup Tb$. How does one show that if $a \in W_i H^n(X_\infty), b \in W_j H^m(X_\infty)$ then $a \cup b \in W_{i+j} H^{n+m}(X_\infty)$ ?

Comment: This is Proposition 1.6.9 (i) of Deligne's Weil II http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1980__52__137_0.pdf